# iText7 PdfHtml - Display Page Number at Footer

Tags: java, spring, pdf-generation, itext7

I am using iText7 - pdfHTML to convert my HTML template into a PDF.

I want to display a `Page X of Y` on my footer; 
However, I always getting Page 1 of 1. (There are 20 pages)

Below is my codebase to convert multiple HTML files into PDF.

```java
// Converter Class file

ByteArrayOutputStream outputBaos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputBaos);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);

...

for (String template : templates) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream tempOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  PdfWriter tempWriter = new PdfWriter(tempOutput);
  PdfDocument tempPdf = new PdfDocument(tempWriter);
  HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(template, tempPdf, converterProperties);
  tempPdf = new PdfDocument(
    new PdfReader(
      new ByteArrayInputStream(tempOutput.tpByteArray())
    )
  );
  merger.merge(tempPdf, 1, tempPdf.getNumberOfPages());
  tempPdf.close();
}

pdf.close();

return outputBaos;
```

```css
// HTML file

@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
  }
}
```

May I know how can I achieve this?

Comment: you should be catching events as new pages are getting created. you can find some of that documentation [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/ebooks/itext-7-converting-html-to-pdf-with-pdfhtml/chapter-4-creating-reports-using-pdfhtml).

Comment: In your current code you convert 20 HTML documents into PDF documents and merge them. In each HTML document you have a page counter and it's converted into `page 1 of 1` which is expected because each HTML is a one-pager. You should either convert a single (merged big) HTML into PDF, or merge them into one PDF without page numbers and then go over all pages to add the desired footer.

Comment: @Wee Hong are you able to proceed with the suggestion above?